# Audit Requirement - Capture Logins vs Database

Tags: sql-server, audit

I have a question, I hope you can give me some guidance based on your high expertise level.

There is an audit requirement where we have to provide login information per databases on a given server. Basically, I’m talking about DB users that authenticate externally to a DB (containment type is None).

How should I proceed to capture this event to answer the following question? “Give me the last login for the DB User XYZ authenticated in DB ABC?”

I couldn’t find anything in SQL Server Audit Specification (SQL 2012). It only works when the DB  has the containment type set to Partial. But I also need to capture logins for SQL 2005 and 2008 databases.

Your help is greatly appreciated, Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not setting up a server level audit with SUCCESSFUL_LOGIN_GROUP and FAILED_LOGIN_GROUP ? If users are mapp through the instance to an unique database, you can surely give the last login connected to it.

Answer (score 0):

For this I would default to extended events for the 2008 server and up. There is a good blog post about it [here.](https://voiceofthedba.wordpress.com/2015/12/16/tracking-logins-with-extended-events/)

Additionally, for the 2005 server, you would need to use a trace as the extended event functionality wasn't available. There was another post for this shown [here.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54494/sql-server-keep-track-of-all-connections-disconnections)

Both of these options give you different ways of storing and what to capture such as login name, time, database name, Etc.