# Find the SQL query that caused an event in the past

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database in which I noticed that one of my tables is missing.

I haven't used this database for over three months and now I want to find out **who caused this**, when this happened, how it happened and what code was used (or generated by SQLMS) for this action.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

This data *might* still be in the default trace, which can roll over and phase out files based not only on activity but also based on service restarts (so I say it *might* be there because you may have restarted SQL Server more than 5 or 6 times in three months, even if there hasn't been a lot of activity).

Anyway, it is one of the examples I included in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/48053/1186), which I'll repeat a portion of here:

> Question: Who deleted the dbo.EmployeeAuditData table and when?

This will return any `DROP` events for an object named `EmployeeAuditData`. If you want to make sure that it only detects `DROP` events for tables, you can add a filter: `ObjectType = 8277` (the [full list is documented here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180953.aspx)). If you want to restrict the search space to a specific database, you can add a filter: `DatabaseName = N'db_name'`.

```
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(260);

SELECT 
   @path = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([path]), 
   CHARINDEX(CHAR(92), REVERSE([path])), 260)) + N'log.trc'
FROM    sys.traces
WHERE   is_default = 1;

SELECT 
  LoginName,
  HostName,
  StartTime,
  ApplicationName
FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(@path, DEFAULT)
WHERE EventClass = 47    -- Object:Deleted
AND EventSubClass = 1
AND ObjectName = N'EmployeeAuditData'
ORDER BY StartTime DESC;
```

Please also see the other answer for additional caveats (e.g. details around the lack of recording of the *schema* of an object that has been dropped, and also the fact that `TextData` will never be populated - not that it will ever be anything varying far from `DROP TABLE dbo.whatever;`).