# SQL Server - Is it possible to forbid creation of default constraint name?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, constraint, default-value

I was having a looking on this [article](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/default-constraint-names) about default constraints and I have a question. Is there a configuration in SQL Server 2008 that forbid naming creation of new default constraints declared without a proper custom name?

In other words, can SQL Server block this:

```
CREATE TABLE Test1 (
   Val1 int DEFAULT -1, 
   Val2 int DEFAULT -2) 
  /*the fields above will generate a strange suffix in default constraint name such as DF__Test1__Val1__32E0915F*/
```

but allow this:

```
CREATE TABLE Test1 (
   Val1 int Test1_Val1_DF DEFAULT -1, 
   Val2 int Test1_Val2_DF DEFAULT -2) 
  /*the fields will use proper custom name in default constraint name*/
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using - Standard, Enterprise ? If Enterprise, then Policy Based Management will help you.

Comment: @Kin The SQL Server is `Standard`. So I won't have available this Policy Based Management?

Comment: Then your best bet is to purchase third party software that enforces standards. @AaronBertrand 's point is valid as `how often people are creating tables that violates your company policy`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could use a DDL trigger if you could build a reliable LIKE expression that determines that a column has been specified with a default but does not contain the word `constraint` before the word `default`. But that won't be very fun. If you don't have PBM you're probably better off just [manually reviewing the DDL in the default trace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48052/what-event-information-can-i-get-by-default-from-sql-server) or having a DDL trigger that e-mails you on create/alter table, and slapping wrists when it happens.

(I mean, how often are people creating tables in a way that violates your corporate naming standard, and why are they still allowed to create tables if they can't follow the rules?)