# Getting the referenced object from SQL Trace

Tags: sql-server

I am able to query the default trace or any SQL trace for the event "Audit Add Role Event" to see if anyone has received any instance level access escalation. What I am trying to figure out is how to get which specific user got added to the role. I am using the query below... I tried using the referenced object column but found that it was null.

```
SELECT TOP 1    TraceFile.[value]
                FROM sys.fn_trace_getinfo(NULL) TraceFile
                WHERE TraceFile.property = 2
---------------------------------------------------------
SELECT  TraceEvent.name AS [EventName],
        Trace.DatabaseName,
        Trace.DatabaseID,
        Trace.NTDomainName,
        Trace.ApplicationName,
        Trace.LoginName,
        Trace.SPID,
        Trace.Duration,
        Trace.StartTime,
        Trace.EndTime
FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(CONVERT(VARCHAR(150), (SELECT TOP 1    TraceFile.[value]
            FROM sys.fn_trace_getinfo(NULL) TraceFile
            WHERE TraceFile.property = 2
                                             )), 4) Trace
    JOIN sys.trace_events TraceEvent ON Trace.EventClass = TraceEvent.trace_event_id
WHERE   TraceEvent.name LIKE 'Audit Add Role Event'
ORDER BY Trace.StartTime;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Audit Add Role Event` is actually auditing the addition of a new role (e.g. `CREATE ROLE`). To audit *adding a new member* to an *existing role*, you want either `108 - Audit Add Login to Server Role Event` or `110 - Audit Add Member to DB Role Event`, depending on which type of role you actually mean.

Here's an example of each:

- Database user added to database role:

  ```
  DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(260);

  SELECT @path = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([path]), 
     CHARINDEX(CHAR(92), REVERSE([path])), 260)) + N'log.trc'
  FROM    sys.traces
  WHERE   is_default = 1;

  SELECT RoleName, TargetUserName, StartTime
  FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(@path, DEFAULT)
  WHERE EventClass = 110
  -- AND DatabaseName = N'YourDatabase'
  ORDER BY StartTime DESC;
  ```
- Login added to server role:

  ```
  DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(260);

  SELECT @path = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([path]), 
     CHARINDEX(CHAR(92), REVERSE([path])), 260)) + N'log.trc'
  FROM    sys.traces
  WHERE   is_default = 1;

  SELECT RoleName, TargetLoginName, StartTime
  FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(@path, DEFAULT)
  WHERE EventClass = 108
  ORDER BY StartTime DESC;
  ```

You can also add other columns from the trace to see what application, host, and login actually performed the action. Combining the two queries above, and adding auditing columns:

```
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(260);

SELECT @path = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([path]), 
   CHARINDEX(CHAR(92), REVERSE([path])), 260)) + N'log.trc'
FROM    sys.traces
WHERE   is_default = 1;

SELECT 
  RoleName, TargetUserName, TargetLoginName, DatabaseName, 
  ApplicationName, HostName, LoginName, StartTime
FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(@path, DEFAULT)
WHERE EventClass IN (108, 110)
AND COALESCE(DatabaseName, N'?') = CASE EventClass 
--   WHEN 110 THEN N'YourDatabase' ELSE N'?' END
ORDER BY StartTime DESC;
```

Now when I do something like this on my system:

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE LOGIN floob WITH PASSWORD = 'x', CHECK_POLICY = OFF
ALTER SERVER ROLE [dbcreator] ADD MEMBER floob;
GO
CREATE DATABASE splunge;
GO
USE splunge;
GO
CREATE USER blat WITHOUT LOGIN;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER blat;
```

I can then run the above query, and I get the following results (leaving audit columns out of the output for brevity):

```
RoleName       TargetUserName  TargetLoginName  DatabaseName  ...audit columns...
-------------  --------------  ---------------  ------------
db_datareader  blat            NULL             splunge      
dbcreator      NULL            floob            master
```

Clean up:

```
DROP USER blat;
GO 
USE master;
GO
DROP DATABASE splunge;
DROP LOGIN floob;
```

Note that this will only tell you about events that haven't been aged out of the default trace, so if you're trying to find out when someone was added to a role last year, it's unlikely you're going to find it.

Also, as an aside, it's much more efficient to hard-code the event IDs in the query than to go look up the classes every time. You can see [how to get the list of available events in any trace here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/48053/1186) (as well as examples of other information you can get from the default trace).

And finally, your `TOP 1` without `ORDER BY` assumes that the default trace will always come out first. This is not necessarily always going to be true, [even if it is what you observe most of the time (see #3)](https://sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/t-sql-tuesday-56-sql-server-assumptions/).