# What is the best way to keep track of all changes implemented on a database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

I am a new DBA to a company and in general. I am planning to do some changes to a database settings such as backup compression, enable some trace flags, create more files in TempDB ets. 
My question is what would be the best way to keep track of all changes and new implemented settings So it can be easy accessible? 
And so people after me can easy access and see what is the current condition of the database? 
Is there maybe special software for that? Or common way that all DBA's are follows? 
I just want to know how to record everything you did on a database? i can write everything down on a piece of paper, word doc, excel or maybe there is a better way of doing that?
Thank you

Comment: I just want to know how to record everything you did on a database? i can write everything down on a piece of paper, word doc, excel or maybe there is a better way of doing that?

Comment: Something to record changes and store information? Why not...a database? Create your own administrative database and store your changes in a table with a timestamp and author.

Comment: Have you considered making your options you need to monitor as a 'policy' and creating Policy Manager entries for it? You can get a lot of it that way.  Also 3rd party tools are great for this stuff.  Ultimately it comes down to how you control your environment and changes though, along with what you need to monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaron Bertrand's post [What event information can I get by default from SQL Server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48052/what-event-information-can-i-get-by-default-from-sql-server) covers the best options available right out of the box, including mining the Default Trace, Extended Events and the Error log. The techniques described can be augmented to log the captured data to permanent tables for long-term auditing.

The SQL Audit feature is also effective, consolidating related commands into various groups allowing the setup of templates based on specific command/event types. Audit data is captured to file and, if the business requires it, the DB engine can be commanded to shut down if SQL Audit data cannot be saved.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have budget for a third party monitoring tool such as [SQL Sentry](https://www.sentryone.com/platform/sql-server-performance-monitoring)?

This will monitor your SQL Server instance for you, far easier than attempting to create your own solution. You can also create additional [Advisory Conditions](https://www.sentryone.com/platform/advisory-conditions) to alert you for any changes you choose.