# How can I get the host_name who creates a DB (proactive mode) in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, audit, management

First, I want to clarify that **I am not looking for a** `SELECT HOST_NAME()`.

I am managing a database environment and have given the developers permission to create the databases they need in the development environment. However, I want to **store** the machine name (`HOST_NAME()`) from where the database is created independent of the database user that they use for that purpose. This way, proactively, when a developer creates a database **in the future** I want to know who creates databases, not only by the owner user but by the name of the machine.

Answer (score 3):

That information is available in the default trace (see [this answer for more detail](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48052/what-event-information-can-i-get-by-default-from-sql-server)), if it hasn't rolled away (the default trace only keeps so much history).

```
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(260);

SELECT 
   @path = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([path]), 
   CHARINDEX(CHAR(92), REVERSE([path])), 260)) + N'log.trc'
FROM    sys.traces
WHERE   is_default = 1;

SELECT 
   LoginName,
   HostName,
   ApplicationName,
   SPID,
   StartTime,
   DatabaseName
FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(@path, DEFAULT)
WHERE EventClass = 46
AND EventSubClass = 1
AND ObjectID IS NULL
AND ObjectType = 16964
-- AND DatabaseName = N'<database name>';
```

Other disclaimers:

- HostName can't always be collected (e.g. connecting to SQL Server from Visual Studio Code on a Mac leaves HostName NULL).
- HostName is easy to spoof.

Going forward, you can do just about anything you want with a DDL trigger, subject to the same disclaimers as above. You can start with something like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE Watchdog;
GO
USE Watchdog;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.CreateDatabaseLog
(
  EventTime datetime2 NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME(),
  HostName nvarchar(128),
  EventData XML
);
GO

USE master;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER CaptureDatabaseCreation
ON ALL SERVER
FOR CREATE_DATABASE
AS
  INSERT Watchdog.dbo.CreateDatabaseLog(HostName, EventData)
    SELECT HostName, EVENTDATA();
GO
```

Now, I'll leave parsing `DatabaseName` out of the XML as an exercise for the reader, mostly because I am late picking up my kids from daycare. :-)

Comment: Thanks for explain me "HostName is easy to spoof." But does it mean that I must have an active trace to determine this? What I really need is to be able to store the name of the machine so it does not have an active follow up.