# Is there a way to catch a dbcc checkident command

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, identity, dbcc

A colleague of mine noticed incorrect ids generated for inserted items. Most probable cause: some script issues a command like the following:

```
dbcc checkident('dbo.table', reseed, 1)
```

I have thought about setting up a DDL trigger to catch this commands, but [this list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522542(v=sql.110).aspx) of DDL events does not seem to include anything related to reseeding.

**Question:** is there a way to catch such commands in a similar way DDL triggers catch various database schema changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, these are captured by the default trace (and maybe by extended events system_health session, not sure). Given the caveats in this answer (for example a command issued last year is unlikely to still exist in the trace):

- [What event information can I get by default from SQL Server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/48052/1186)

You can see recent DBCC events here:

```
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(260);

SELECT @path = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([path]), 
       CHARINDEX(CHAR(92), REVERSE([path])), 260)) + N'log.trc'
FROM   sys.traces
WHERE  is_default = 1;

SELECT TextData, ApplicationName, LoginName, StartTime, DatabaseName
  FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(@path, DEFAULT)
  WHERE EventClass = 116
  --AND DatabaseName = DB_NAME() / or constant
  ORDER BY StartTime DESC;
```

Note, this will show more than just `CHECKIDENT` events, but you can filter that further. On the other hand, it might be useful to spot check what other DBCC commands are (or are not) being run, though.

Comment: Since I am interested in what happened very recently, this is very good for me. Thanks.