# `select OBJECT_ID(N'X')` takes "forever"

Tags: sql-server

I have encountered strange state of a SQL Server. In one particular database in this SQL Server `select OBJECT_ID(N'X')` takes "forever". How to diagnose what is going on?

*EDIT:* Problem disappeared. However, I am still curious what was going on.

Comment: The likely cause is blocking. An uncommitted DDL transaction will block the function.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It is really strange because no one was doing any DDL transaction.

Comment: @TN. How do you know that?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Access to the db is restricted. (It is semi-production database.)

Comment: That doesn't mean DDL can't be happening.

Comment: How to identify what was causing DDL transactions taking hours?

Comment: You probably have to catch it in the act, or if it's after the fact, hope that it's something that was captured in the default trace *and* you still have enough of the trace data left to see it (see [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/48052/1186)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OBJECT_ID()` (and several other metadata functions) have to observe locks taken against objects, and wait for them to be released. I generally recommend against their use because, unless you actually *want* to wait for the lock to release (which is totally valid, but uncommon), you end up getting blocked. This is what I suspect happened here, though there is no way to prove it now.

I blogged about this here:

- [Bad habits : Using (certain) metadata "helper" functions](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-metadata-helper-functions)

The workaround is, instead of using the functions, pull the values from the catalog views. It's more code, but it will obey isolation semantics, unlike the functions, which won't. So instead of:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.foo'); 
-- actually won't obey isolation level
```

You say:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
-- will obey isolation level
SELECT o.[object_id] 
  FROM sys.objects AS o
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
  ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
  WHERE s.name = N'dbo'
  AND o.name = N'foo';
```

Again, it's more code, but you've found the price of convenience here. It's a shame schema name isn't exposed as a computed column; I wrote a tip about creating your own views to get around this and other complexities here:

- [Making SQL Server metadata queries easier with these new Views](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3449/making-sql-server-metadata-queries-easier-with-these-new-views/)