# SQL Server: Who created an audit and who altered it last?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, audit

I am trying to find out who created an audit (found under Audits) but I don't seem to have any luck. I've already tried many queries such as these:

[Blog 1](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23161317/SQL-Server-how-to-find-out-who-created-db-object-table-sproc-trigger-etc.html), [Blog 2](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/4191/how-to-find-user-created-objects-in-system-databas.html), [Blog 3](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Security001.htm)
And

```
SELECT *
FROM   [sys].[objects]
SELEcT * FROM sys.server_audits
```

They seem to work for all other objects, but not for audit. I need to know which user created the audit and which user altered it last. **sys.server_audits** does not help.

Answer (score 1):

A trace isn't a database-level object, so none of those queries you were reading about had any chance. The [default trace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/48052/1186) has this information, though, under event 117 (`AUDIT CHANGE AUDIT EVENT`) - assuming you haven't disabled it and that the audit was created recently enough that it's still there (it's a rolling trace).

```
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(260);

SELECT 
   @path = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([path]), 
   CHARINDEX(CHAR(92), REVERSE([path])), 260)) + N'log.trc'
FROM    sys.traces
WHERE   is_default = 1;

SELECT * 
  FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(@path, DEFAULT)
  WHERE EventClass = 117
  ORDER BY StartTime DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you. This actually did not return any results. The trace was created 1 year ago.

Comment: @LearnByReading When the *trace* was created isn't relevant. It's how much data you're collecting in the trace. Older events will get pushed off.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check to see if a server audit specification was mapped to the audit and if the AUDIT_CHANGE_GROUP action type was included. The last modification to the audit and/or its state may end up being logged in the audit files as a result.