# How to check user defined schemata creation date in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I want to find Schema creation date and user who created schema in SQL server,
I am unable to find information in  system views.

Note: Not asking about schema scoped objects

Comment: If you are not asking about "database schema", then which "schema creation" are you asking about?

Comment: User defined schemas

Comment: And how is that different than a "database schema"? You are talking about those things created using `create schema` are you?

Comment: Yes, I want to know where actually created date  information in stored in sql server like other objects we find in sys.objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find the information in `sys.traces` as long as the information not reset which happens upon service restart.

If that's not the case, try following query, but this is quick solution, the proper solution in your case is [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) which stores the selected trace events information outsize SQL Databases, so that you can retrieve  and monitor such event info whenever you need since the captured data won't be retested upon service restart.

For more details on [all event classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/sql-server-event-class-reference?view=sql-server-2017) and [sys.traces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-traces-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
select PATH, Trace.*
from sys.traces AS T
        CROSS APPLY fn_trace_gettable(T.path, default) as Trace
Where ObjectName like '%YourSchema%'
go
```

Comment: If trace is not enabled?

Comment: Is there is any other way other than traces and extended events

Comment: @NavyasriBalina You disabled the [default trace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/48052/1186)? Why?

Comment: @NavyasriBalina, Hope, Mr. Aaron Bertrand's [Q&A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48052/what-event-information-can-i-get-by-default-from-sql-server) made your concern and comment more clear!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a reliable way... but given that, having created a schema, you're going to create your first object in it pretty soon after that:

```
select [schema_id], min(create_date) create_date
 from sys.all_objects with (nolock)
 group by [schema_id]
```